# DataFormatString not working for Html.EditorFor

Tags: c#, html, date, model-view-controller

I have created a form that has a date of birth property, which I want to show in `dd/MM/yyyy` format but it shows in  `MM/dd/yyyy` format. I have tried so many solutions from here but none of them have worked as expected.

This is my model

```
[Display(Name ="Date Of Birth")]
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]        
public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
```

This is View

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.DateOfBirth, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", style = "display:inline;"} })
```

I have tried `@Value = Model.DateOfBirth.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")` which gave me null reference error.

**EDIT:** so I changed the date format from my operating system(windows 10) from english(US) to english(india) which worked for my DateOfBirth property.

is there any other way of doing it within my project?

Comment: Read the first note in [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.displayformatattribute.dataformatstring?view=netframework-4.8) for that property and see whether that's relevant to your case.

Comment: @user18387401 I did try those but it didn't work.